# How to change the starting directory in Visual Studio code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, directory

When I try to run any program, it says "terminal process failed, starting directory does not exist" (bottom right in the image).
So I changed the terminal>integrated cwd to a different path, it still says path the old path does not exist.
How do I change the starting directly?
Everyone and everything says it is terminal>integrated cwd, but it is not working.[image]

I have tried searching for the old directory in VScode, but I can't find it.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want a default path for your terminal just set this cwd option as empty. That way your terminal will open in the "root path" being the "root" the place you are right now, if you open a folder at `C:\Users\yourname\yourfolder` your terminal will be opened there, if you open your folder at `C:\Users\yourname\yourotherfolder\foo\bar` your terminal will be opened at `...\foo\bar`.

If you're editing the configs from the `settings.json` and not from the UI option, change the `"terminal.integrated.cwd"` option to `""`.

Maybe you where trying to change that config to set a default interpreter path? Like instead of open `cmd` or `powershell` by defaul open the `Git Bash` one? If so, you can change it at `Terminal > Integrated > Default Profile: Windows`. To do it on `settings.json` will be `"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "Git Bash"` or whatever that you want, `"powershell"` to powershell, etc.

Comment: Putting terminal>cwd as empty does not solve the "starting directory  does not exist" error.

Comment: can you send me your `settings.json`? do `Ctrl+shift+P > Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)`

Comment: {
    "C_Cpp.updateChannel": "Insiders",
    "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
    "code-runner.runInTerminal": true,
    "kite.showWelcomeNotificationOnStartup": false,
    "code-runner.cwd": "C:\\Users\\Swarnim\\code"
}

Comment: @user541396 try to set the `"code-runner.cwd"`  to `""` and tell me what happens (or just remove the config, the `""` will be the default)

Comment: Nothing changed,  still says terminal process failed, Starting Directory not found.

Comment: changing in to "" does not allow me use Terminal > new Terminal.

Comment: Just removing the configuration instead of changing to `""` also dont allow you to use terminal?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242882/discussion-between-luigi-minardi-and-user541396).

Comment: Also, try to check your extensions to see if some of them do something related to your terminal or your `code working directory` (cwd) cuz I really can't reproduce your error here

Answer (score 0):

It's the `User` setting, could you open the `Workspace` setting? It's just next to the `User` setting.